# how do i get gender from facebook public profile Facebook IOS Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

The reason why I need to get the gender of the Facebook user is because my app is only cater for women and by getting the gender of the user could solve a lot of the app problem.

The code

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(_, _, let accessToken):

                if let userId = accessToken.userId {

                }


            }
        }
```

The result that I get from the facebook server

```
["picture": {
    data =     {
        height = 200;
        "is_silhouette" = 1;
        url = "https://www.picture.com";
        width = 200;
    };
}, "last_name": Test, "email": test123@gmail.com, "id": 1234556, "first_name": Airsoft]
```

I didn't get the gender of the user. How do I get the gender of the user?

Regards

Comment: Check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

Comment: @Rajesh gender is under public_profile

Comment: How would I get the gender only?

Comment: read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get these details using Graph api. Check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

```
      let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(user-id)", parameters: ["fields" : "id,name,email,birthday,gender,hometown" ], httpMethod: "GET")
      request?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        // Handle the result
      })
```