# Facebook Login Not Reading Gender - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app stopped reading user gender and I can't seem to figure out why... It's pulling in the other 3 parameters I am requesting except gender. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    func getFacebookUserInfo() {
    if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
    {
        //print permissions, such as public_profile
        print(FBSDKAccessToken.current().permissions)
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, name, email, gender"])
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()

        connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            let userID : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
            let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]
            print("Data:\(data)")
            let FBid = data["id"] as! String
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(FBid)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1")!
            let picLink = String(describing: url)

            self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["userPic": picLink])

            self.label.text = data["name"] as? String
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)! as Data)

            let name = data["name"] as! String

            self.ref.child("users").child(userID).updateChildValues(["name": "\(name)"])
            self.ref.child("leaderboard").child(userID).updateChildValues(["name": "\(name)"])

            let gender = data["gender"] as! String

            self.ref.child("users").child(userID).updateChildValues(["gender": "\(gender.capitalized)"])
            self.ref.child("leaderboard").child(userID).updateChildValues(["gender": "\(gender.capitalized)"])

            self.ref.child("leaderboard").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.hasChild("barScore"){

                    print("score exists")

                }else{

                    self.ref.child("leaderboard").child(userID).updateChildValues(["barScore": 0])
                }
            })


        })
        connection.start()
    }
}
```

The error is occurring at let gender = data["gender"] as! String

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

On the print data line this is the output:

Data:["id": 10210000000080261, "name": John Doe, "email": j.doe@gmail.com]

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303959/6080920 try this

Comment: What API version are you using? (You are making unversioned calls, so it should be the lowest one your app can use, depending on when it was created.) You now need to ask for permission [`user_gender`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_gender) before you can access someone’s gender.